# $A\in M_n(C)$ such that $x^*Ax=0\; \forall x\in C^n,$ then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A\in M_n(C)$ such that $x^*Ax=0\; \forall x\in C^n,$ then $A=0$

I was able to show $A_{ii}=0 \; \forall 1\leq i \leq n$ by taking $x=e_i$

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\langle Ax, y\rangle:=y^*Ax.$

Then $$0=\langle A(\alpha x+ y), \alpha x+ y\rangle=\alpha\langle A(x), y\rangle+\overline\alpha\langle A(y), x\rangle.$$
Consider the cases $\alpha=i$ and $\alpha=1$. Adding the two equations, we get $\langle A(x), y\rangle=0.$ Now take $y=Ax$.

Answer (score 1):

To continue your idea you may now consider

- $e_k^{\star}Ae_l$ with $A=\left(a_{kl}\right)$

A quick calculation shows that
$$e_k^{\star}Ae_l = a_{kl}$$

Using this consider

$$(e_k + e_l)^{\star}A(e_k + e_l) = (e_k^{\star} + e_l^{\star})A(e_k + e_l)= \boxed{a_{kl} + a_{lk} = 0}$$
$$(e_k + ie_l)^{\star}A(e_k + e_l) = (e_k^{\star} -i e_l^{\star})A(e_k + ie_l)= ia_{kl} - ia_{lk} = \boxed{i(a_{kl} - a_{lk}) = 0}$$

From this follows immediately that $a_{kl} = a_{lk} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A more general result:

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A,B \in B(H)$, i.e. they are bounded linear operators. Then we have that
$$\forall x \in H: (Ax|x)=(Bx|x) \implies A=B$$

And the proof relies on the polarization formula for complex Hilbert spaces:

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A \in B(H)$. Then $\forall x,y \in H$, we have that
$$(Ax|y)=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^3 i^n (A(x+i^n y)|x+i^n y)$$